# Is there a COUNTIF function in Excel which does the entire dataset? (Or something similar in R)

Tags: r, excel, duplicates, counting

I have a dataset in Excel with 4 columns and 8 rows, the first column being types and there are duplicate entries. Columns 2 to 4 are people and the cells are counts of events (sample set). I am not interested in adding up counts for each type per person, what I am after is how many types are found for each person.
I can use the =SUMIF(range, criteria, {sum_range]) formula for the person A and in a second step remove the 'zero' counts and get the number of types, going one person at a time. My dataset has thousands of types and hundreds of names so that's not an option.

In essence, it would be about removing duplicates from the column type and indicating in the other columns with a yes/no or true/false if that person has that type.

Is there a formula which does all persons at once?

| type | person A | person B | person C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 45 | 23462 |
| b | 456 | 3452 | 0 |
| c | 0 | 4 | 4536 |
| d | 56 | 0 | 1 |
| d | 9 | 1235 | 8 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| c | 78 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an `R` answer for you. (In the future, please provide your data in an easy-to-copy format!)

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b", "c"), 
                 person_a = c(0, 456, 0, 56, 9, 0, 78), 
                 person_b = c(45, 3452, 4, 0, 1235, 0, 0),
                 person_c = c(23462, 0, 4536, 1, 8, 0, 0))

df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -c(type), names_to = "person", values_to = "count") |> 
  dplyr::group_by(person) |> 
  dplyr::filter(count != 0) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(num_types = length(unique(type))) |>
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

This results in a nice little table:

| person | num_types |
| --- | --- |
| person_a | 3 |
| person_b | 4 |
| person_c | 3 |

This answer will scale for any arbitrary number of types and people. If your data frame contains other non-person columns that you don't want to aggregate, you could even modify the pivoting as follows: `tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = tidyselect::starts_with("person"), names_to = "person", values_to = "count")`. If you want to remove the "person" prefix, add the following parameter to the `pivot_longer` call: `names_prefix = "person_"`.

**EDIT**

Is this what you wanted?

```
df |> 
  dplyr::group_by(type) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(dplyr::starts_with("person"), 
                   function(person) as.numeric(max(person) > 0)))
```

The table would look like this:

| type | person_a | person_b | person_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| c | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| d | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Basically, we summarize the columns of `df` that start with "person" to be 1 if at least one of the rows for that type has a positive count and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and effort. I am a beginner only, also with this website. About the table, there seems to be a misunderstanding, maybe I didn't word it clear enough. I am after a table which has all the types with duplicates removed in one column and the following columns one person after the other if this person has the type or not. The types are actually genera of bacteria. I want to know the genera found in each person not just the number of genera.

Comment: Check out the edit to the answer—is that what you wanted? If so, please mark as correct; if not, sketch out the table you want and I'll help you fill it in!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried array formulas (also referred to as CSE formulas)? Described here: https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/cse-array-formulas-excel/

You can use multiple conditions (if statements) chained together. I frequently will use a SUM(IF([condition 1],IF([condition 2],1,0),0)) to make the equivalent of a multi condition count.

Comment: I don't know much about array formulas and I had a look at MrExcel. It doesn't seem to do the trick since it goes one column at a time with the only advantage that you can copy the formula. I thought more along the lines of having to split the set so each participant is aligned with the column type and then sum each one and carry that through for everyone - just that I don't know if that's possible or how to do it. The COUNTIF function I pt in the headline may be a bit m,isleading since it is possibly more likely to be the SUM function...

Comment: Please post complete answers in the "answers" section. This sort of response is better as a comment (so you'll have to build up some reputation points!).